# django / joined query

Tags: python, django, sqlite

Checked all docs and questions/answers here but not succesfull. Need your help.
I've experience in pure PHP and MySQL, but frameworks kills me.

My models;

```
class Projects(models.Model):
id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
subject= models.CharField(max_length=50)
sender= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)#inserting django's default user id
```

This is django's default but edited `auth_user` table

```
    CREATE TABLE "auth_user"  (
  "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
  "password" varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  "last_login" datetime NULL,
  "is_superuser" bool NOT NULL,
  "username" varchar(150) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  "first_name" varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  "last_name" varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  "email" varchar(254) NOT NULL,
  "is_staff" bool NOT NULL,
  "is_active" bool NOT NULL,
  "date_joined" datetime NOT NULL,
  "tck_no" varchar(11) NOT NULL
)
```

When I want to fetch my project, I use normally;

```
SELECT u.*, p.* FROM users u, projects p WHERE u.id=p.sender;
```

Above code returns all fields on both table normally.

In django viewmodel;

```
@login_required(login_url="/login/")
def others_projects(request):
projectlist = Projects.objects.all().filter(sender_id=request.user.id)
```

Above code returns Projects table fields, but can not figured how to get first_name field matched record from users foreign key used?

Comment: I believe you can shorten your project list by using `projectlist = Projects.objects.filter(sender=request.user)` This being said, if you need the user `first_name`, couldn't you just use the existing User object?  `request.user.first_name`

Comment: I have to get from the query. This sample shows loggedin user's projects, thats ok, but when I use .filter(~Q(sender_id=request.user.id)) for other user's projects, it will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are iterating through your `projectlist` you could access it as such.

```
projectlist = Projects.objects.filter(sender=request.user)
for p in projectlist :
    print(f'First name is {p.sender.first_name}')
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/

Comment: So much thank you. Always thinked about query line.